# Terminology for wireless communication where only one of the things needs to be powered?

Tags: signal-analysis

What's the terminology for a two things that interact wirelessly but requires that both have power or electricity? For example, Bluetooth requires that both devices have power at all times to interact. Same thing with wifi devices.

Conversely, what is it called when only one of the two devices requires power, while the other doesn't need to be powered? For example, a contactless smart card isn't powered but can still interact with the powered terminal. Another example is a metal detector; the piece of metal underground is obviously not powered but can still interact with the powered metal detector.

Comment: In your examples of things that interact with only one of the devices needing power, the devices without power do not _interact_ with the device with the power, but are _read_ or _sensed_ by the powered device.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I believe you are looking for is “passive”. Passive RFID tags do not require an internal power source to operate, and are powered by the EM field emitted by the reader.

Comment: Another related term would be backscatter communications (which I think your RFID tag example falls under). There are also energy harvesters that collect energy from rf, light, etc to power a communication system (usually at a very low duty cycle).